# Laravel: js/app.js - Source-Map-Error :request failed with status 404

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

I'm fairly new to laravel and I get always this error message in the browser console

> Source-Map-Error: request failed with status 404
>   Ressource-Adress: http://[myurl]/js/app.js
>   Source-Map-Adress: popper.js.map

And I have no idea where the problem is. When I try to access the app.js file through the URL it works.

I have a second project with the exact same setup where I don't get any errors. I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are missing a source map. what is your JS setup atm? i.e. what dependencies are you pulling in? Can we see source ?
Something like this might help

```
app.import('node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js.map', { destDir: 'assets' });
```

Comment: I'm very new to laravel. Where can I find this information?

Comment: Are you starting a brand new project, or are you looking at someone else's code? popper.js looks like a dependency inside app.js.. try pasting app.js into your question.